# MySQL: #1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '...'

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers

I'm trying to create a MySQL query to update PAN no of all members.

Using the query below I keep getting this error and its not something I've come across before, google seems to offer a variety of answers but I'm unable to relate the fix to my query.

```
UPDATE if_membermaster SET PAN_No = 'ABCD1234D' WHERE 'MemberCode'  = 5100
```

Result:

> ```
> ERROR:- #1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'MemberCode'
> ```

`MemberCode` is `int(9) DEFAULT NULL`.

Can any one help to fix this ?

Comment: Are those single quotes around membercode?

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong quotes (PEBCAK). The where clause is comparing the *string* `'MemberCode'` with 5100. This forces MySQL to convert both values to *double* hence the warning. Change single quotes to backticks:

```
UPDATE if_membermaster SET PAN_No = 'ABCD1234D' WHERE `MemberCode` = 5100
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my time.